# Android - Sending .wav file using RETROFIT2 for Speaker Recognition

Tags: android, httprequest, speech-recognition, retrofit2, voice-recognition

I'm trying to send a .wav file using Retrofit2 on Android in order to use the Create Enrollment request of the Microsoft Speaker Recognition API  (https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56406930e597ed20c8d8549c)

But I always get the following Error 400:

```
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/OkHttp: <-- 400 Bad Request https://api.projectoxford.ai/spid/v1.0/verificationProfiles/94BC205B-FACD-42A7-9D80-485403106627/enroll (3907ms)
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/OkHttp: Pragma: no-cache
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 123
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/OkHttp: Expires: -1
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/OkHttp: X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/OkHttp: apim-request-id: e5472946-ec90-4662-a3c9-dda62c2c6b27
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 12 Aug 2016 11:43:04 GMT
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/OkHttp: }
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (123-byte body)
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/EnableVoiceRecognition: Upload success
com.mobile.cir.voicerecognition D/error message: RequestError{code='null', message='null'}
```

Here is my Apiclient class:

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging).build();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

The POST request:

```
 @Multipart
 @POST("verificationProfiles/{VerificationProfileId}/enroll")
 Call<EnrollmentResponse> createEnrollment(@Path("VerificationProfileId") String profileId,
                                           @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
                                           @Header("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key") String subscriptionKey,
                                           @Part("file") RequestBody audioFile);
}
```

And the action itself:

```
File audioFile = new File(fileDirectory + "my_voice.wav");
RequestBody requestAudioFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), audioFile);
Call<EnrollmentResponse> call = apiService.createEnrollment(PROFILE_ID_TEST,"audio/wav; samplerate=1600",API_KEY,requestAudioFile);
call.enqueue(new Callback<EnrollmentResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<EnrollmentResponse> call, Response<EnrollmentResponse> response) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Upload success");
        RequestError error = ErrorUtils.parseError(response);
        Log.d("error message", error.toString());
        Log.d(TAG,"Response: " + response.body().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<EnrollmentResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Upload error: " + t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Where am I doing wrong?

## * EDIT *

Microsoft developers released the Android library for this API
(https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-SpeakerRecognition-Android)

Comment: Are you following the audio duration constraints? "The audio file should be at least 1-second-long and no longer than 15 seconds. "

Comment: Yes, I did. The audio is 7/8 second long.